# C++: store list of lambda functions

Tags: c++, function, templates, variadic-templates

I need to create a vector that will store void functions with different number of parameters. I used variadic templates for this, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class...Types>
using MyFun = std::function<void(Types...)>;

std::vector<MyFun<>> operators;

template<class Lambda>
void addOperator(Lambda lambda)
{
    operators.emplace_back(lambda);
}

int main()
{
    auto f1 = [](int a, int b){std::cout<<a+b;};
    auto f2 = [](double a, double b){std::cout<<a+b;};
    addOperator(f1);
    addOperator(f2);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the purpose of this list? How do you want to call these functions?

Comment: How would you then use these functions if you don't know their parameters types? You can use a vector of `std::any`, but then what?

Comment: Every instatiation of `MyFun` is a different distinct type. You can't store them in the same container without some kind of type-erasure. `std::function` comes to mind, but that won't work for different function signatures. You should re-think your design. This doesn't look like a good approach for a statically typed language.

Comment: The solution could be std::variant or std::any or something else depending on your requirements.

Comment: It is impossible to design that kind of software, not only that it can not be written. When functions have different signatures, you will never be able to give useful parameters to them.

Comment: similar questions come up frequently. They almost never talk about calling the functions, or what to do with them once you placed them inside a container, but thats the important part. Consider that you can place anything into a container of `void*` but there is almost nothing that you can do with such container

Comment: you could for example read the parameters from a stream and forward them to functions of different signature, but once you do that you will realize that the right interface is not functions of different signatures, but functions that take a stream as parameter

Comment: This question clearly suffers from [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). @JoungCPPser pelase explain why you need this functionality, what are kind of functionality you want to have (do not describe how you are planing to achieve it since it is clear it doesn't work).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a small number of possible types, here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <variant>
#include <vector>

// this helper is from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit
template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... {
  using Ts::operator()...;
};

template <class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

int main() {
  using T1 = void (*)(int, int);
  using T2 = void (*)(double, double);

  T1 const f1 = [](int a, int b) { printf("int add: %d\n", a + b); };
  T2 const f2 = [](double a, double b) { printf("double add: %f\n", a + b); };

  std::vector<std::variant<T1, T2>> vec{f1, f2};
  // add more elements if needed

  for (auto const& f : vec) {
    // example usage
    std::visit(overloaded([](T1 const& f) { f(1, 2); },
                          [](T2 const& f) { f(1.5, 2.3); }), f);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [anyfunc](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/anyfunc.hpp), which is an upgraded `std::any`, that allows invocation. You can just do:

```
std::vector<gnr::anyfunc> v;
```

Just like you would with a `std::any`, but you need to remember the exact function signature of the functor you stored, though this can be hacked around, if you write your own `anyfunc`. Anyway, here's an [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BjgKdgQevZ6My0ah).

```
std::vector<gnr::anyfunc<>> v{
  [&](){ std::cout << "yay" << std::endl; },
  [&](int const i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};

v[0]();
v[1](1);
```

But this is just one example. You can even store [coroutines](https://github.com/user1095108/cr2/blob/master/listdemo.cpp) in lists without any problems.